# Recursividad en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo el siguiente programa con una función RECURSIVA la cuál debe devolver una nueva lista cuyos elementos serán la suma de los elementos que ocupan la misma posición en cada una de las dos listas de entrada.

Ejemplo:

entrada:

```
listaA = [0, 1, 464, 2, 9]
listaB = [0, 154, 5465, 6, 1]
```

salida:

```
[0, 155, 5929, 8, 10]
```

El código:

```
import modulo_auxiliar

lista1 = [0, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3]
lista2 = [7, 1, 3]
suma = modulo_auxiliar.suma_listas(lista1, lista2)
print(suma)


def suma_listas(lista1, lista2):
    nueva_lista = []
    contador = 0
    if type(numbers1) and type(numbers2) == list:
        suma = numbers1[0] + numbers2[0]
        nueva_lista.append(suma)
        contador += 1
        return nueva_lista
```

La salida de mi código es `[7]` que son los valores que ocupan las respectivas posiciones

Comment: En este código no hay recursividad alguna ...  de hecho no hay un solo bucle. Lo que hace actualmente es sumarte el primer elemento de ambas listas `0 + 7 = 7 `...

Comment: Como dice @eferion, no hay recursividad. Lo que haces, es comparar los datos para ver si se pueden sumar y sumas el x[0] + y[0]. El contador, si te das cuenta, ni lo usas, (sabes que necesitas un contador, pero no para que). El contador lo usarias para elegir la proxima posicion del array asi: x[contador] asi iras recorriendo el array. Tambien necesitas un bucle, no un condicional, con el if, sumaras la posicion que pongas en [] si el if es true, y saldra, necesitas un while, o for. Dale una vuelta al codigo y cuando tengas algo mas, pregunta otra vez. Animo.

Comment: No sé cual es la pregunta, he hecho control + f de "?" y no me ha dado resultados :/

Comment: Muchisímas gracias por la ayuda @cupax64. He conseguido resolver finalmente el ejercicio

Answer (score 1):

Ok, para @Matilde, veo que ya te han solucionado el problema, de todas formas aquí te dejo el código arreglado, sirve para sumar 2 listas de cualquier tamaño:

```
    def suma_listas(lista1, lista2):
        nueva_lista = []
        if type(lista1) and type(lista2) == list:
            minlista = min([len(lista1), len(lista2)])
            maxlista = max([len(lista1), len(lista2)])
            for i in range(minlista):
                suma = lista1[i] + lista2[i]
                nueva_lista.append(suma)
            if len(lista1) == maxlista:
                nueva_lista += lista1[minlista:]
            elif len(lista2) == maxlista:
                nueva_lista += lista2[minlista:]
        return nueva_lista


    lista1 = [0, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3]
    lista2 = [7, 1, 3]
    suma = suma_listas(lista1, lista2)
    print(suma)

 [7, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3]
```

Adicionalmente se puede usar la función map de esta forma:

```
    a = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, lista1, lista2))
    print(a)
```

Pero solo funciona con listas que tengan el mismo tamaño, si son diferentes, solo sumará los objetos que estén en la misma posición, y el resultado será una lista de solo esas sumas: [7, 5, 9]

Asumo que deseas que el resultado que contenga la suma de las 2 listas más los objetos que no tienen suma, que se da cuando las listas son de tamaños diferentes, pero en caso de que solo quieres las sumas de los elementos que tienen su par, solo debes de quitarles los if del código y el max, quedando así:

```
def suma_listas(lista1, lista2):
    nueva_lista = []
    if type(lista1) and type(lista2) == list:
        minlista = min([len(lista1), len(lista2)])
        for i in range(minlista):
            suma = lista1[i] + lista2[i]
            nueva_lista.append(suma)
    return nueva_lista
```

Espero te ayude en algo.

Ahora para @Irene, la forma recursiva es esta:

```
def sumalistasiguallongrec(lis1, lis2):
    lisres = []
    if len(lis1) == 0 and len(lis2) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(lis1) == 0 or len(lis2) == 0:
        if len(lis1) == 0:
            for i in lis2:
                lisres.append(i)
        elif len(lis2) == 0:
            for i in lis1:
                lisres.append(i)
    else:
        lisres.append(lis1[0] + lis2[0])
        lisres += sumalistasiguallongrec(lis1[1:], lis2[1:])
    return lisres


primeraLista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
segundaLista = [9, 9, 9]
print(sumalistasiguallongrec(primeraLista, segundaLista))
```

Te dará como resultado la suma de listas, más los elementos solitarios, esto cuando las listas son de tamaños diferentes, aquí el código para que la lista resultante sea solo los elementos en común:

```
def sumalistasiguallongrec(lis1, lis2):
    lisres = []
    if len(lis1) == 0 or len(lis2) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        lisres.append(lis1[0] + lis2[0])
        lisres += sumalistasiguallongrec(lis1[1:], lis2[1:])
    return lisres
```

Espero que ayude.